# How to specify output of command 'padrino rake routes'

Tags: rake, padrino

I currently have multiple controllers but am only interested in seeing the terminal output of

```
padrino rake routes
```

for a specific controller. Is there a flag that can achieve this. Or commandline regex?

Thanks internet!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest using pipes to pass the output of the `padrino rake routes` command to `awk` to filter only the lines which the name of your controller, or the number of the row is less than 4 (to include the preamble)

```
padrino rake routes | awk '/:your_controller_name/ || NR < 4'
```